# Unity JSON string array into objects from cUrl

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, json-deserialization

I am not sure how to accomplish this. I am getting some users from an www request like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic "+System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user*pass")));
WWW www = new WWW("https://somedomain.com:8000/users", null, headers);
yield return www;
Debug.Log(www.text);
```

The debug returns this:

```
[{"user_id":"ho896ty6","user_name":"Mikje Flanders","age":43},{"user_id":"ft357hj","user_name":"Anna Simpson","age":56}]
```

Now, I have an object like this:

```
public class userData
{
    string user_id;
    string user_name;
    int age;
}
```

which i would like to get the data into, but not sure when the json is an array. I tried like this, but with no luck:

```
userData thisUser = JsonUtility.FromJson<userData>(www.text);
```

Hope someone can help me with this and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: your json is always an array or may be sometimes its an object?

Comment: Youd don't need NewtonSoft to deserialize array. JsonUtility with a simple wrpapper should be able to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to parse the Json using delimiters, unless your using visual studio in that case, check your nuget for `Newtonsoft.Json`  with this package installed you can:

```
  Using NewtonSoft.Json;
```

List udat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject>(json);

```
   foreach( userData data in udat){
   //do something here to each item;
   }
```

using [jsoneditoronline](https://jsoneditoronline.org/)

```
[
  {
    "user_id": "ho896ty6",
    "user_name": "Mikje Flanders",
    "age": 43
  },
  {
    "user_id": "ft357hj",
    "user_name": "Anna Simpson",
    "age": 56
  }
]
```

i cleaned up your code a little so you can see what your doing.
added some getters and setters to your class...

it looks like your getting more than one userData return in your request, so you may need a list or array. if you need help with that let me know!

```
  public class userData
    {
       public string user_id {get;set;}
       public string user_name{get;set;}
       public int age{get;set;}
    }

public class userList
{
public List<userData> users{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I got an issue with the "udat" in foreach( userData data in udat){}. It has a red line below and I cant get it to work... Hope you can help.

Comment: my bad udat.users

Comment: Well, that solved that, but now i got this issue: JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'userList' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Comment: i updated the code to parse to a list directly, did notice the answer below mine is on the same track @ershoaib!

Comment: Perfect, it did the job :-)

Comment: You can't add the Nuget Package Newtonsoft.Json when using unity. When running the game, unity compiler will throw an error about it.

Comment: @MohamadMousheimish, You are in some misconception here. Its perfectly working and acceptable by question owner. You couldn't downvote answers if its not working in your case. Kindly undonwvote answers.

Comment: @MohamadMousheimish, Think upon that,  If it's throwing the error then question owner doesn't accept an answer. Trying to upgrade and downgrade nuget package of newtosoft either its conflicted with your version of unity. If you ask about this before donwvote then I'll assit you to fix your problem.

Comment: @MohamadMousheimish, Which error compiler throwing? Let me know I'll try to provide you a solution.

Answer (score 2):

1) Install `Newtonsoft.json` from `Nuget Package Manager` and add reference to your program
like `using Newtonsoft.Json;`

2) This is your user model class

```
public class User
{
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public string user_name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

3) Then deserialize your json to your model like

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Sample json i get in variable
        var json = @"[{'user_id':'ho896ty6','user_name':'Mikje Flanders','age':43},{'user_id':'ft357hj','user_name':'Anna Simpson','age':56}]";

        //This line convert your string json to c# object
        List<User> userList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(json);

        //Loop through to get each object inside users list
        foreach (User user in userList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"user_id: {user.user_id},  user_name: {user.user_name}, age: {user.age}");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Try once may it help you.

Comment: @Mansa, view the answer might be it help you :)

Comment: Perfect, it did the job :-)